# Referencing cells on another sheet through appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using google sheets, I'm trying to reference a cell on another spreadsheet (called setup). The cell will format if the data on the cell B2 on the sheet named setup.

```
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('B2')])
  .whenTextContains('setup!B2')
  .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
```

This doesn't seem to be working. Is there any way to reference cell B2 in the setup sheet (this is what I did       *.whenTextContains('setup!B2')*)

Comment: Just wanted to confirm, you would want the conditional formatting rule to apply if the cell is referenced from another sheet, is that correct?

Comment: That's right. Basically, I want cell B2 on sheet 1 to change to #B7E1CD if the contents within are the same as those on cell B2 on sheet 2 (whose name is setup).

Comment: Alright, so Bryan's answer should do the trick if ever you would want to compare cell values for your conditional formatting. I'll be posting a different alternative if you would want to get the cell formula instead of the cell value.

Comment: Sounds great thanks. I haven't tried his solution out yet but I will do so when I have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.whenTextContains() requires a String, when using your current code the formatting rule will apply if the values are specifically "setup!B2", if you want the values in cell B2 at sheet setup you'll need to use a different method:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("setup").getRange("B2").getValue();
```

You can try this modification:

```
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  var newValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("setup").getRange("B2").getValue();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('B2')])
  .whenTextContains(newValue)
  .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
```

Resources:

- [Range.getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())

Comment: So I tried to run the program but the execution log says that the spread sheet is not defined, even though you seemed to have defined the spreadsheet. Is there anything else I should add to this function?

Comment: Scratch that you were right, I just got it to work.

Comment: Turns out I had to delete some of my original functions. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative:**

```
function setBGonFormula() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var cell = spreadsheet.getRange('B2');
  var formula = cell.getFormula(); 
  if(formula == '=Setup!B2'){
    cell.setBackground('#B7E1CD');
  }

}
```

This is a sample implementation if you aim to get the cell formula as a condition to set the background colour of your choice.

Reference:

[getFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula)

Comment: So I tried to run this formula but so far nothing happened. No formatting occurred on either sheet 1 or 2.

Comment: Disregard that last message. I had to delete some other functions to make it work. Thanks for your help!